# Creating `option` with Underscore

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js

Given the following:

```js
function autoCompleteOptions(json) {
        _.map(json, function(x) {
            const a = x["a"];
            const b = x["b"];
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.setAttribute('data-value', a);
            option.value = b;
            console.log('option:', option);
            return option;
        })
    }

var result = autoCompleteOptions([
    {
      "a" : "hi", 
      "b" : "world"
    }
  ]);

console.log('result:', result);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Why does the `console.log` show `undefined`? I'm expecting an array of `option` HTML Elements.

Comment: Because your function (`autoCompleteOptions`) doesn't explicitly return a value?

Comment: In your snippet it looks like you are not including `underscore.js`

Comment: There is no JSON in this code. JSON is a format for encoding data as a string. You've got an array and an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to return the result of `_.map` from your function

```
   return _.map(json, function(x) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is merely an issue with how Stackoverflow works. You're trying to load the `_` library from a non-secure source (`http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js`), but SO uses `https`.

Load it from a secure source like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js to fix the `_` is not defined issue.

As a secondary issue, and as the others have pointed out, you need to return something from the `autoCompleteOptions` function.

```js
function autoCompleteOptions(json) {
  return _.map(json, function(x) {
    const a = x["a"];
    const b = x["b"];
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute('data-value', a);
    option.value = b;
    console.log('option:', option);
    return option;
  })
}

var result = autoCompleteOptions([{
  "a": "hi",
  "b": "world"
}]);

console.log('result:', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```